# Change where the theme gets its files from

Tags: 6, hooks

I'm a beginning developer and I am working in this one **Drupal 6** website that has multiple websites in the root. To add to the complexity, I am working with the module Mobile_tools to direct users to a mobile theme.

My issue lies with the sharing of images. When users are directed to the mobile theme, I want to find a way to specify where the website grabs it's images from. It seems that by default, it grabs them from the /sites/all/files rather than the /sites/all/themes/theme/files location.

What would be the best way to go about changing this location? I was thinking of implementing a hook override, but have no idea where to or how to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[drupal_get_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/6) and [path_to_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/6) are the two functions that will be usefull for u.

Comment: Thanks! I have resorted to these functions and was able to get the appropriate results.